# My android code for Google account authentication deosn't have any error but it can't be run on AVD. It always crashes

Tags: android, firebase, authentication

I have tried to create Google Account log in button on my Android application. However, it never works out. It always crashes and there is no error shown. Here is catlog of my file;

> ```
> java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient: int com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient.zzach() failed to verify: int com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient.zzach(): [0xF] 'this' argument 'Reference: com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability' not instance of 'Precise Reference: com.google.android.gms.common.zzf' (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient' appears in /data/app/com.example.myapplication-Sn3CYWA_970KQ2a5e8Gjvg==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk)
>     at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn.getClient(Unknown Source:0)
> ```

I need some help on my code what is worng with it or something is missing

Comment: does your avd has play services installed  and active google account associated ?

Comment: I bulit an APK file and tested on my Android phone. The APK file was not intalled successfully as well.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I added a few dependencies in the app level gradle file and it worked for me.

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
```

Don't forget to add this at the end.

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Hope this helps.